# Extract specific frequency from Modulated signal using FFT

Tags: java, fft, dft

I've modulated a carrier frequency signal with my data using FSK like this:

```
double SAMPLING_TIME = 1.0 / 441000 // 44khz
int SAMPLES_PER_BIT = 136;
int ENCODING_SAMPLES_PER_BIT = SAMPLES_PER_BIT / 2;
int duration = ENCODING_SAMPLES_PER_BIT * SAMPLING_TIME;

public double[] encode(int[] bits) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
        int freq = FREQUENCY_LOW;
        if (bits[i] > 1)
          freq = FREQUENCY_HIGH;
        bitArray = generateTone(freq, duration);
        message = bitArray;
        }
     return message;
}
private double[] generateTone(int frequency, double duration) {
        int samplingRate = 1/SAMPLING_TIME; // Hz
        int numberOfSamples = (int) (duration * samplingRate);
        samplingTime = 2 * SAMPLING_TIME;

        double[] tone = new double[numberOfSamples];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; i++) {
            double y = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * frequency * i * SAMPLING_TIME);
            tone[i] = y * CARRIER_AMPLITUDE;
        }
        return tone;
    }
```

Clearly, I'm sending FREQUENCY_LOW for ZERO and FREQUENCY_HIGH for 1.

**Now how do I demodulate it using FFT?** I'm interested in sampling magnitudes (presence and absence) of FREQUENCY_LOW, FREQUENCY_HIGH throughout the time.

I only know basics of FFT, I was starting to write this but it doesn't make sense:

```
private void decode(byte[] tone, int length) {
    float[] input = new float[FFT_SIZE*2]; // not sure what size? shouldn't this be buffer?
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        input[i]=tone[i];
    }
    FloatFFT_1D fft = new FloatFFT_1D(FFT_SIZE);
    fft.realForward(input);
}
```

Can someone help with code?

Comment: if you are only tracking a few frequencies, you don't need to use fft.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overlapping sliding windows for your FFTs, with the window and FFT the same length as that of your data bits.  Then look for magnitude peaks for your 1's and 0's in the appropriate FFT result bins across these windows.  You will also need some synchronization logic for runs of 1's and 0's.

Another DSP techniques that may be less compute intensive is to do quadrature demodulation for your two frequencies and low-pass filter the result before feeding it to the synchronization logic and bit detector.  Yet another possibility is two sliding Goertzel filters.

Comment: sorry I mentioned im new to FFT, not sure if I understand how to put that to code. Can you help with the code?